# Adding an extra class name to all td classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to extra class name with every exist class.
for example for now I have this scenario.

```
<table id="Table20">
  <tr>
    <td class="item">
    <td class="item">
    <td class="item">
     <td class="item">
     <td class="item">
  </tr>

  </table>
```

And I want to add an extra class with Jquery like this one:

```
<table id="Table20">
    <tr>
  <td class="item itm1">
  <td class="item itm2">
  <td class="item itm3">
  <td class="item itm4">
  <td class="item itm5">
 </tr>

</table>
```

I were using that code but it does not work for me.

```
$('td.item').each(function(i,n){ $(n).addClass('count' + (i + 1));});
```

Please help.

Thank you

Comment: This code looks fine. Maybe the problem is your concatenating `count` instead of `itm`

Comment: BTW - Well written question

Comment: Is that your actual table code? You're missing the closing `</td>` tags for all your cells.

Comment: Sorry about missing the </td> tag..

Comment: sorry about the difference of count and itm, actually the code doesn't work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('td.item').each(function(i,n){
        j= i+1;
        $(this).addClass('itm'+j);   
    });
});
</script>
<table id="Table20">
<tr>
<td class="item">1</td>
<td class="item">2</td>
<td class="item">3</td>
<td class="item">4</td>
<td class="item">5</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for creating this code. but I added this code on my site the extra class isn't added.

Comment: thanks its working fine, but some classes came from ajax loading and this code isn't applying on them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like below:

```
 $(function() {

     $("td").each(function(i) {
       var nclass = this.className;
       var trimmedClass = (nclass.slice(0,-1));
       var nCLass = trimmedClass + i; 
      $(this).addClass(nCLass);
      });
    });
```